# Returning the linenumber of a matching substring in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to return the line number in a file that always has the same prefix, but the rest may vary.

Is it possible to search a file using only stock Windows components and Commandline operating utilities to return the line number of the matching part.

An example of the line I am searching for is:

`</TR></TABLE><TABLE cellspacing...` *More code that may vary*

The line in the file is the output of a generator and so I am not sure what has changed or may change every time it generates the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINDSTR is used to search for text in a file, printing out each line that matches the search. The `/N` option causes the line number to be prepended to each matching line of output as `LineNumber:FullTextOfMatchingLine`.

Since your search string includes a space, you must use the `/C:"search string"` option, otherwise the search string is interpreted as multiple search terms delimited by space.

You want the search to only match the beginning of the line, so you need the `/B` option. Alternatively you could add the `/R` option to treat the search as a regular expression and then use the `^` beginning-of-line anchor at the start of your search string.

```
findstr /b /c:"</TR></TABLE><TABLE cellspacing" "yourFile.htm"
```

You ask for only the line number, without the text of the matching line. You can use FOR /F to extract out the desired line number(s).

```
for /f "delims=:" %A in ('findstr /b /c:"</TR></TABLE><TABLE cellspacing" "yourFile.htm"') do @echo %A
```

If you put the command in a batch file then you must double the percents:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /b /c:"</TR></TABLE><TABLE cellspacing" "yourFile.htm"') do echo %%A
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `findstr /N strings filename` to search for instances of `strings` in the file `filename`.

Note: `/N` "Prints the line number before each line that matches"

For more usage information, run `findstr /?`